# Use encrypted password for logging in open fire through jsxc

Tags: openfire, strophe

I'm using JSXC as a client side chat solution so i need to pass my login details to server to do the login process,

```
jsxc.init({
    xmpp: {
        url: 'http://hasan-pc:7070/http-bind/'
    },
    root: '/MAM/resources/assets/global/jsxc',
    autoLang: false,
    defaultLang: 'fr'
});

$(function(){
    var myItems;
    $.getJSON('resources/assets/global/jsxc/test.json', function(data) {
        myItems = data;
        jsxc.storage.setItem('debug', false);
        var rid= ''+Math.random()+'';
        rid=rid.substr(2, 12)
        var username = myItems.username;
        var password = myItems.password;
        var domain = myItems.domain;
        var jid = username + '@'+domain;
        jsxc.start(jid , password);
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log("Error!");
    });;
});
```

I need to know how can i send a encrypted password and validate it server-side in openfire, which class in open fire is the listener then i can change the behavior.
and i would be happy if anyone else has a better idea to have an encrypted login.
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Use HTTPS, everything except the host name will be encrypted.

Comment: actually i encrypt the password myself and i just want to check them server side my self too, i need to know which class should i use to check the password server side my self